# copy and paste on textarea won't work on mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

if i copy a text paragraph and paste it on a textarea for an update content my mysql database won't update the content but when i type it manually on the textarea, the mysql database will then be update the content..how can i update the content in the mysql using copy and paste method

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$main = $_POST['main'];

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_content SET main ='$main' WHERE users = '$name' 

}

<textarea name="mep" id="mep" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Textarea is named `mep` not `main`.

```
$main = $_POST['mep'];
```

Please provide more information. And that C/P thing doesn't make sense, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
 $main = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['main']);
```

ah, and what @webarto said.